# dbContext with DBSet<some IInterface>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface, repository, dbcontext

I have the following highly simplified code to try out using an interface in
a DBset (see below).

When I remove from the context the DBSet with the interface and run,

```
  var r =  locaDatabase.Entities.First(); ---- WORKS AS EXPECTED
```

However, when I add the interfaced DBSet into the context as per below. It
won't compile. It gives an error stating that the cast from DbSet
to (DbSet)EntityAddresses is not possible.

CS0030: Cannot convert type from ... to ....

I've search thoroughly stack overflow for answers and tried so many things, none have worked.
.Cast, Set, more etc....

There seems to be a more fundamental problem with this even being a possibility.

The big picture is this. I want to create an interface for my context, create interfaces
for my entities, then have the assembly containing the application (which references EF Core)
use the context interface and the entities as interfaces.

I know this is really simplified code but the application DOES work. Until I start converting
it to using interfaces instead. Note: I have the interface for my context too, but haven't started
on testing using that yet, I wanted to start with simply trying to use entity interfaces first and
then move on to more in-depth stuff next.

Thanks

```
    public class LocalSQLiteDatabaseDbContext : DbContext
    {

     public virtual DbSet<EntityAddress> EntityAddresses
     {
        get;

        set;
     }

     public virtual DbSet<IEntityAddress> EntityAddresses
     {
        get
          {
           return (DbSet<IEntityAddress>)EntityAddresses;
          }


        set 
          {
           .....
          }

       ...... the rest.....

     }// End class

    public class EntityAddress : IEntityAddress, INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

         private long _EntityAddressID;

         private string _Street;

        ...... the rest.....

    } // End class


    public interface IEntityAddress
    {

      long EntityAddressID { get; set; }

      string Street { get; set; }

      ...... the rest.....

    } // End interface
```

Comment: When a DbSet<tableclass> is declared in a dbcontext the tableclass contains everything that EntityFramework needs to know to about the table.  Best to use the actual tableclass, not an interface.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext